# unable to fetch pdf from webviewer on localhost due to possible CORS error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, ruby, cors

I am unable to fetch pdf only on localhost.
[image: Network wrror]

However, CORS is being handled on the application helper end

```
  def allow_cors    
    if request.host.include?("simplifyem.com") or request.host.include?("localhost") or request.host.include?("0.0.0.0")
      response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
      response.headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = 'GET, PATCH, PUT, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE'
      response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
    end
  end
```

Any insight on this would be appreciated.

Comment: the gem rack-cors is not used in the application.  I dont think it is required as other PDFs are being fetched. The only was its being handled is by before_filter :allow_cors